# TypeScript Generics TypedArray: TypedArray is not assignable to T

Tags: typescript

I'm learning about generics, and hitting this issue with the compiler:

```
type FloatArray = Float32Array | Float64Array;
type IntegerArray =
  | Int8Array
  | Uint8Array
  | Int16Array
  | Uint16Array
  | Int32Array
  | Uint32Array
  | Uint8ClampedArray;
type TypedArray = FloatArray | IntegerArray;

export function identityArray<T extends TypedArray>(array: T): T {
  return array.subarray(0);
}
// Type 'TypedArray' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution without a type assertion:

```
type TypedArray = FloatArray | IntegerArray;
type WithSubArray<T extends TypedArray> = { subarray(begin?: number, end?: number): T };

export function identityArray<T extends TypedArray>(array: WithSubArray<T>): T {
    return array.subarray(0);
}

const res1 = identityArray(new Int8Array(2)) // Int8Array 
const res2 = identityArray(new Float32Array(2)) // Float32Array 
const res3 = identityArray([1, 2, 3]) // ✖
```

If `T` is declared as function return type, make sure to also return `T` exactly in the function body. By using `WithSubArray` we can make it clear to the compiler, that `array.subarray` returns `T` and not `TypedArray`.

[TS Playground to try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgewIbAIICd1JFAvLRFAZgCYMscAfA5YANgBZzsBuAWAChRIoBJAO2AQA5hHTMcuTlBlRqA4AA4J02dQCqAS0HLM2VTPmCAjHRUdZcqFpNm9IA1YWlzljduAv7j9zoDCcEgAtpAAJhLsHJzc0AAq4BDh9ng0KBJOgiJiEdEJUADqmsAAFgDKAK4ARhIAPLFQEAAeQvyhAM5Q8WESAHwpAN5QbVVI9gAUlSLaAPwAXFD85UGT6AA0Da1zC0srAJTz9QC+kbk8hSUV1faocMB1Dc0QrR1dib0pAEoQAMYI6KE1ABEw0qowogPWYwAdDDRsI2vMAAqjYIQIToNp1BJJCgAbWBI3sgIAuj1dng+rEepxOE0wH9gFAAGblfjfYCaBD8KCaUJPDmgWr1JotdqdbG9MZg7Dzc5lKpCskHKD9RzoNHldDc6UgKEgnVjAAMu0ihxpHF+-DajPVbWMKV5-KKIAkY34EAA7nwdK6SLtyQB6APepTpQC8G4AZHc4lutUFtJAdfMEztd7q98FoXgoYz9geDGeIZGSkejXNjtqIiadgvGuOM6xI6yIxLzUEAaOTmzscIA)

Answer (score 1):

From docs, just type cast your return line.

> “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast...

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

```
type FloatArray = Float32Array | Float64Array;
type IntegerArray =
    | Int8Array
    | Uint8Array
    | Int16Array
    | Uint16Array
    | Int32Array
    | Uint32Array
    | Uint8ClampedArray;
type TypedArray = FloatArray | IntegerArray;

export function identityArray<T extends TypedArray>(array: T): T {
    return <T>array.subarray(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but it still feels like I'm overriding the compiler. Shouldn't there be a way for this to work without the type assertion?